# PHP $_FILES clean up

Tags: php, html, arrays, file-upload

I am getting a messy `$_FILES` array using PHP.

I get this:

```
Array([data] => 
    Array(
        [name] => Array ([T1] => Array ([V1] => dummy.jpg )) 
        [type] => Array ([T1] => Array ([V1] => image/jpeg )) 
        [tmp_name] => Array ( [T1] => Array ([V1] => /tmp/domains/bc3/phpIPIlOG)) 
        [error] => Array ([T1] => Array ([V1] => 0)) 
        [size] => Array ([T1] => Array ([V1] => 89682)) 
    )
)
```

I want this:

```
Array ([data] => 
    Array ([T1] => 
        Array ([V1] =>
            Array ( 
                [name] => dummy.jpg  
                [type] => image/jpeg 
                [tmp_name] => /tmp/domains/bc3/phpIPIlOG  
                [error] => 0 
                [size] => 89682 
           ) 
       ) 
   )
```

)

The name of the HTML-form-field is: data[T1][V1]

I am looking for a generic PHP solution where multiple files can be uploaded and different naming structure.

Comment: Can you share your `HTML`?

Comment: <input type="file" name="data[T1][V1]"> I am not interested in changing the HTML.

Comment: So do you want to manipulate the `$_FILES` to your required output in `php`?

Comment: yes. I want to reorder the PHP array

Comment: @SahilGulati, dont give up, when you are close to :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this function](https://gist.github.com/faizalheesyam/7782125).

```
function rearrange_files($arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $key => $all)
    {
        foreach($all as $i => $val)
        {
            $new_array[$i][$key] = $val;    
        }    
    }
    return $new_array;
}

$newFiles = rearrange_files($_FILES);
```

Comment: This works on the example with two levels on the input/name array. Problem is if having more levels. Basically, it is easy to make a hard coded solution. The challenge is to make a generic solution reordering the messy $_FILES for whatever naming structure.